# Add Unity WebGL to Flutter Web

Tags: unity-game-engine, flutter-web, unity-webgl

I am trying to add the unity WebGL to a flutter website.

I have searched everywhere on how to do this but no answer seems to help me do this.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with [Unity-webview plugin](https://github.com/gree/unity-webview)
I had tried using the same build it with webGL and follow up it file structure errors in browsers. You can achieve this same.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working using [easy_web_view2](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_web_view2) package. The Unity game was hosted on a different domain and it was called within this widget. The package more or like mimics IframeElement.